# Attach image to ActionLink in MVC 4

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, actionlink

I am using ActionLink with id in MVC 4 app and assinging actionLink id an image in css but on on earth I am doing wrong. is not working! here is my code

```
 <div class="logo_container">
            @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Index", "Home", null, new { id = "_Logo" })
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
.logo_container {
width:339px;
height:116px; 
}

#_Logo {
background-image: url("../Images/logo.png");
 width:339px;
height:116px;
background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use <a href="@Url.Action(...)">? In your browser html inspector does your <a> element have the class "logo"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from my application. Works ok:

```
.logo{
background:no-repeat url(/Content/photo/png/sprite.png) 0 0;
height:15px;
width:20px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
border:none;
display:inline;
}

<a href="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")" class="logo"></a>
```

Answer (score 6):

The best way you can do for both Html.ActionLink and Ajax.ActionLink is as below

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home").ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Content/img/logo.png\" ... />"))


@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="dvTest"}).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Contents/img/logo.png\" … />"))
```

additionaly you want to provide class and style so you can do as following

```
@Html.Raw(@Ajax.ActionLink("[replacetext]", "Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId="dvTest"}).ToHtmlString().Replace("[replacetext]", "<img src=\"/Contents/img/logo.png\" style=\"width:10%\" … />"))
```

Comment: Thanx Brad, Instate of unescape [\"] I used [']. which works neater.

Answer (score 5):

use your custom HtmlHelper:

```
    namespace Order.Web.UI.Infrastructure
{
    public static class CustomHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ImageActionLink(this HtmlHelper html, string imageSource, string url)
        {
            string imageActionLink = string.Format("<a href=\"{0},\"><img width=\"150\" height=\"150\" src=\"{1}\" /></a>",url,imageSource);

            return new MvcHtmlString(imageActionLink);
        }
    }
}
```

then in your view.cshtml:

```
@using OrderPad2.Web.UI.Infrastructure
.
.
.
.
@Html.ImageActionLink(@app.Icon,@app.AppStoreLink)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only needed to change:

```
new { id = "_logo"}
```

to:

```
new { @id = "_logo"}
```

Without the `@` in front of `id` it treats it as a parameter instead of a attribute of the html element.

**Without** the `@`, it would produce:

> www.site.com/home/index/_logo

**With** the `@`, it would produce:

> www.site.com/home

and the element would be:

```
<a id="_logo" href=""></a>
```