# How to insert an image in ActionLink (View model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, html.actionlink

I want to display an image for each bike, but these codes didn't work:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var bike in Model.Bikes)
 {
     <li>@Html.ActionLink(bike.Name, "Categories", new { id = bike.Id, name = bike.Name, @class = "image"}, null)</li> 
 } 
</ul>
```

Anybody can help me with this, thanks a lot!

I just updated my CSS file:

```
a.image {
    background: url('~/Store Project(new)/Store Project/AdventureCycle/Content/Images/') no-repeat center right; 
    display: block; 
    height: 84px; 
    width: 264px;
}
```

Comment: See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596444/html-actionlink-as-a-button-or-an-image-not-a-link) and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245343/attach-image-to-actionlink-in-mvc-4). Please learn to use the "search tool".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no inbuilt html helpers for Image Hyperlinks.we have to create custom html helper inorder to get this requirement.So refer the below links you will get an idea.

[Action Image MVC3 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896439/action-image-mvc3-razor)

Based upon your comment.i give the solution like this:

```
@if (Convert.ToString( bike.Name) == null || Convert.ToString(bike.Name) == "")
            {
                bike.Name = "Empty";
            }
            @Html.ActionLink(Convert.ToString(bike.Name), "Categories", new { @id =bike.Id, @name = bike.Name },new{ @class = "image" })
```

Here i gave "Empty" if bike.Name is Null or Empty.

Comment: <ul>
    @foreach (var bike in Model.Bikes)
     {
      <li> <%=Html.Action(bike.Name, "Categories", new {id = bike.Id, name = bike.Name,null ,@()class="image"}) %></li>
     } 
    </ul>

And in CSS

    a.image {
        background: url('~/Store Project(new)/Store Project/AdventureCycle/Content/Images/Mountain-bike-jump.jpg') no-repeat center right; 
        display: block; 
        height: 84px; 
        width: 264px;
    }

I fixed it already, but it still didn't work.

Comment: r u using razor view engine or aspx view engine.For Razor:use this.@Html.ActionLinkFor
 (bike.Name, "Categories", new {@id = bike.Id, @name = bike.Name,@class="image"})

Comment: **Html.ActionLinkFor**... didn't appear in razor view

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer. :)

Comment: do you  get solution?

Comment: if you fullfill with the answer.Accept the answer.It will help to others

Comment: Hi Ajay! I just updated my CSS above. And I fixed exactly the solution you recommended, but it still not work.

Comment: run the application in chrome and press f12.if you see any error?in the panel(F12)

Comment: I ran it and it comes the error like this **Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain** .

Comment: hai dude you mention location not image i.e;"~/Store Project(new)/Store Project/AdventureCycle/Content/Images/" Make it into "~/Store Project(new)/Store Project/AdventureCycle/Content/Images/yourimage.jpg"